# Video grid with vstack and hstack

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to combine four videos into a grid. Currently I'm using `vstack` to combine the rows and then `hstack` to combine the two outputs, as well as adding the audio.

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -i 1.mp4 -ss 8 -i 3.mp4 -filter_complex vstack left.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 0 -i 2.mp4 -ss 0 -i 4.mp4 -filter_complex vstack right.mp4
ffmpeg -i left.mp4 -i right.mp4 -filter_complex hstack -i audio.mp4 output.mp4
```

[It seams possible to do this in one operation using `overlay` and `pad`.](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/FilteringGuide#multipleinputoverlayin2x2grid) However, the documentation states that using [`vstack`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack) and [`hstack`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) is faster. Can those two filters be combined to one single operation?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[image]

You can do it all in one command using the [hstack](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hstack) and [vstack](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#vstack) filters.

```
ffmpeg -i top_l.mp4 -i top_r.mp4 -i bottom_l.mp4 -i bottom_r.mp4 -i audio.mp4 \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]hstack[t];[2:v][3:v]hstack[b];[t][b]vstack[v]" \
-map "[v]" -map 4:a -c:a copy -shortest output.mp4
```

- The audio will be [stream copied](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) from `audio.mp4` instead of being needlessly re-encoded.

If you want the audio from each input to be combined instead of providing a separate audio input then use the [amerge](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) filter. `-ac 2` is added to downmix to stereo; otherwise the output would have a cumulative number of audio channels.

```
ffmpeg -i top_l.mp4 -i top_r.mp4 -i bottom_l.mp4 -i bottom_r.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v][1:v]hstack[t];[2:v][3:v]hstack[b];[t][b]vstack[v]; \
 [0:a][1:a][2:a][3:a]amerge=inputs=4[a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" -ac 2 -shortest output.mp4
```

Comment: Great! But that filter looks a bit confusing. I cannot get the audio input to work. See the question for the error message.

Comment: Works fantastically. Thank you!

Comment: @MeinAccount There was a typo that @Mulvya fixed. I just added a few more options, so now it will stream copy the audio instead of re-encoding with `-c:a copy`, and finish encoding when the shortest input stream ends with `-shortest`.

Comment: Thanks. Even faster processing.

Comment: A brief description or a link for further reading would be nice. For instance, ffmpeg filters are documented here: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html

Comment: @MartinR. Usually I provide links to filters used in my answers, but they were already present in the question in this case. I'll add them anyway.

Comment: also consider if you have more than 2 inputs, you have to provide the number of inputs like this `[0][1][2]hstack=inputs=3[top]; ...`